# Retrofit causing Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 153 path $.joining

Tags: android, json, spring, spring-boot, retrofit

I am using a REST API created by me using SpringBoot.When I tried tested using Postman I am getting a valid JSON,but Retrofit causes this issue.[image]

I have checked the ModelClass and it is not causing an issue.
I have other POST methods which are working absolutely fine but an issue is occuring with GET method.
The Retrofit is as follows:

```
public class RetrofitService {

    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    //addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))

    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://Location/api/v1/")
            .client(client)
            //.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    public static Retrofit createService() {
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

The Repository is:

```
public class HomeFragRepository {

    private Networking networking;
    private MutableLiveData<EmployeeClass> mutableUserDetails;

    public HomeFragRepository() {
        networking= RetrofitService.createService().create(Networking.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<EmployeeClass> getUserHomeDetails(Long userId){

        mutableUserDetails=new MutableLiveData<>();
        networking.employeeHomeDetails(userId).enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EmployeeClass> call, Response<EmployeeClass> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.i("Response",response.body().toString());
                    mutableUserDetails.setValue(response.body());
                   
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        EmployeeClass employeeClass=new Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody().string(),
                                EmployeeClass.class);
                        Log.i("HelloLogin",employeeClass.getMessage());
                        mutableUserDetails.setValue(employeeClass);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EmployeeClass> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return mutableUserDetails;
    }
}
```

The Employee Model Class is same in Spring and Android so it is not causing any issue.
The GET Method in Spring is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<EmployeeClass> getEmployee(@RequestParam(value="userId") Long userId){
         EmployeeClass employeeClass=attendanceService.searchEmployee(userId);
         return new ResponseEntity<>(employeeClass,HttpStatus.valueOf(employeeClass.getStatus()));
    }
```

This is somehow producing a String instead of a JSON.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when you're receiving something other than the expected response from the server.
It because because you mentioned EmployeeClass in Call so what happens is
the object block in your json response has no name so it is unable to find the object...
try to use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> getEmployee(@RequestParam(value="userId") 
Long userId){
     EmployeeClass employeeClass=attendanceService.searchEmployee(userId);
     return new ResponseEntity<> 
(employeeClass,HttpStatus.valueOf(employeeClass.getStatus()));
    }
```

then parse json manually to get data and save it in your model

or you can try to add @Headers({"Accept: application/json"}) in Retrofit interface see if it works

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/json"})
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful,but the problem I faced was while working with Localdate so changed it to String and now Retrofit is recieving a valid JSON.